# Hide navigation bar according to user role

Tags: javascript, html

Hey everyone i have tried to make three different navigationbars according to the users role. I only want one of the nav bars to be displayed according to if its a guest, user or admin. For now i just want to show the different navigationbar accoring to x=1 or not (se js code).

Can someone help me? I have tired everything by now. But it just wont work. Iam not that good at programming, so please dont make it to complicated.

```
Javascript file
x = 1

if (x==0) {
    (#alle).show;
} else {
    ("#all").hide;
}

if (x==0){
    ("#user").show;
} else {
    ("#user").hide;
}

if (x==101){
    ("#admin").show;
} else {
    ("#admin").hide;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```js
document.querySelector('#all').style.display = 'none';
```

There is no built-in methods `.hide()` or `.show()` like jQuery has.

Comment: Thank a lot, show I refer to the JS file at the beginning of the HTML or at the end?

Comment: At the end, when all HTML elements will be available.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct then this is what you have to do:

```js
x = 0;

//Check role, could also do this in switch statement. 
//But for now like this since it might be easyer to understand. 
//Probably if you copy paste this it wont work but I think this part is needed.
if (user == guest) {
   x = 0;
} else if (user == user) {
   x = 1;
} else if (user == admin) {
   x = 2;
}


//Guest
if (x==0) {
    (#alle).show;
} else {
    ("#alle").hide;
}

//user
if (x==1){
    ("#user").show;
} else {
    ("#user").hide;
}

//Admin
if (x==2){
    ("#admin").show;
} else {
    ("#admin").hide;
}
```